# Obtain remaining calls count on twitter api rate limit Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, rate-limiting

I am using Twitter::REST::Client twitter gem to do some API calls. Is it possible to know how many requests are left in my limit, so I don't call the API too much to get an "Rate limit exceeded" message?

The call that I am interested in is:

```
TWITTER_CLIENT.user("some_user").followers_count
```